# jcrop - how to stop the non-selected area from being greyed out

Tags: jquery, jcrop

I would like to use the jquery tool to select a region of an image but I do not want the non-selected part of the image to be greyed out. Since I know next to nothing about jquery and css I was hoping someone might point me in the right direction about how to do this with jcrop

thank you in advance for any help you can give

Comment: i don't to sound rude but, it might be better for everyone if you at least attempt to implement it first. you've already narrowed down a plugin to help you, perhaps consult it's documentation and if you get stuck along the way, come back and ask a more specific question in regards to your problem. because at the moment it jsut sounds like you want the stackoverflow community to build it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the background opacity

```
$('#cropbox').Jcrop({
    bgOpacity: 1,
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZDBNp/

http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Manual.html#Setting_Options